# Postgresql could not accept SSL connection: sslv3 alert certificate unknown

Tags: java, postgresql, ssl, spring-boot

I'm using SpringBoot with configuration datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://...../mydb?ssl=true&sslFactory=....nonValidating...

in my application.yml

```
port: 8443
ssl:
 enabled: true
 key-alias: PGSQLServerHostNameHere
 key-store: keystore.jks
 key-store-password:....
 key-store-type: JKS
 trust-store: #this one is irrelevant, it's just a...
 ### ... trust store for other restTemplate stuff
 trust-store-password: ....
 key-password: ....
 ciphers: "TLSv1.2"
 protocol: TLS
```

However, Postgresql also is setup and running with SSL=on. ssl_ciphers='TLSv1.2'

However in PGSQL logs I get:

```
Postgresql could not accept SSL connection: sslv3 alert certificate unknown
```

I get an error in my spring boot app on prod (this error doesn't happen with my self-signed cert in local):

```
org.postgresql...PSQLException: SSL error: sun.security.validator.ValdiatorException: PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

**SSL Cert Configs**

I have the signed certificates in root.crt for postgresql server (including the Java app server's signed certificate inside with the right alias).

I have the signed certificate of the postgresql server (alias: PGSQLServerHostNameHere) in the JKS file as a "trustEntry" for my keystore.jks.

I have privateKeyEntry in my keystore.jks for my own server.

I have the root CAs in the keystore.jks.

The SpringBoot app works fine in my local machine with a self-signed JKS.

But Postgresql is a problem... rejecting my communications from the java app server.

postgresql.conf:

```
ssl = on
ssl_ciphers = 'TLSv1.2'

(everything else is default)
```

pg_hba.conf

```
hostssl all all md5
```

Comment: "*I have privateKeyEntry in my keystore.jks for my own server.*"  <= Sounds like [the culprit](https://serverfault.com/questions/639837/openssl-s-client-shows-alert-certificate-unknown-but-all-server-certificates-app). You sure that the client isn't sending the certificate as client authenticator and the postgres server chokes because it does not handle client cert auth?

Comment: @dhke Not sure (I'm not an SSL expert). I have client RestTemplate stuff for another website, for which I just needed a trustStore.  For java Spring Boot connection to my own PGSQL, I believe I needed a private key + signed cert (using openssl creating pkcs12 file), then import pkcs12 into keytool jks with private-key and then the signed cert for PGSQL (using keytool import) into my keystore.jks file. I have no idea about client-auth stuff.

Comment: The SSL configuration you have is for the HTTPS part and isn't used for anything else (afaik).

Comment: @M.Deinum Are you saying SpringBoot doesn't automatically configure it via -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/keystore/keystore.jks ?? That I have to add these command-line options in addition?

Comment: That is exactly what I'm saying. Those SSL settings are for configuring the HTTPS connector of the servlet container not for general SSL. For that reason those properties are in the `server` namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the only way was to look at JSSE implementation and add `-Djavax.net.ssl` type commands to command-line or to add it to `System.setProperty()`.

Additionally, you can add it to the url of the JDBC `ssl_cert=... &ssl_key=...` etc.

Had to find the right commands for postgresql. It's not well-documented.

the `application.yml` "ssl" properties are unrelated to `javax.net.ssl`

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Postgresql could not accept SSL connection: sslv3 alert certificate unknown
> ....
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> ```

This means that the client could not accept the certificate from the server, probably because the CA which issued that certificate is not in the trust store. And the client sends this server this problem as alert so that the server knows why the connection fails.

> But Postgresql is a problem... rejecting my communications from the java app server.

No, your Java application is rejecting the communication with Postgresql because it does not trust the certificate. What you see in the error message from Postgresql is just what your Java application has send as the reason why it will not continue with the TLS handshake.

Comment: Yes I agree I think the way the error is displayed is a bit vague. I think you're right tho. However, I don't know how to fix it. I have the public signed cert+privatekey of java server in "keystore.jks". I have the public signed cert of PGSQL server in the "keystore.jks". PGSQL server has the public signed cert of Java server in root.crt (trust CAs) including the root+intermediary inside. What more could possibly be needed? Both sides have each others signed public cert. Both sides have their own private key configured. Both sides have RootCA+Intermediary. That's everything... I need theories

Comment: @Dexter: I'm not familiar with requirements for JDBC (like if the certificate must have a specific subject). Also, I cannot see from your description how exactly the certificate look. And are you sure that you are using the correct key store?

Comment: That's what I cannot find documentation on. I have a trustStore for client-comms to another server. A keystore for SSL comms to Postgresql. But maybe these two conflict with each other. It's not clear where I'm instructed to put my keystore+truststore (assuming it's ssl.key-store) but maybe that's only for HTTPS not JDBC. Maybe tutorials/docs always assume people use default CAcerts for JDK.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich The error message literally says *PostgreSQL* could not accept the connection, so unless you are suggesting postgresql is the client here, you are wrong.

Comment: I am currently facing the same issue and I can see postgresql complaining in its own console: "could not accept SSL connection: sslv3 alert certificate unknown"; my point being the problem can not be blamed on the client, and to be honest not even on the postgresql - it can be either of these two... either client is identifying itself with fckd certificate or postgresql wasn't configured properly (it should have the certificate in the ca-file, in case the client certificate is self-signed)

Comment: @JaroslavZáruba: The client (Java) is telling the server (PostgreSQL) that it will not accept the certificate the server has send. This information is send in form of a TLS alert from client to server.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Let me get this straight, "Postgresql could not accept SSL connection", this is what you read as "client is telling postgresql that it will not accept..."? Just making sure we both are talking about the same error message.

Comment: @JaroslavZáruba: Correct, the TLS handshake (and thus the SSL_accept in the PostgreSQL) failed because the client could not verify the certificate. The client therefore ended the handshake with an error and told the server within a TLS alert of this problem. The server logged the problem.